# Odd/even q-point mesh in harmonic phonon density of states (DoS) calculations

Tags: phonons, convergence-test, phonon-density-of-state, q-points

[image]

Total DoS for two different q-point grids, $100\times100\times100$ and $101\times101\times101$, are graphed above. The DoS for $63\times63\times63$, $65\times65\times65$, $71\times71\times71$, *$72\times72\times72$*, $81\times81\times81$, $85\times85\times85$, and $101\times101\times101$ are same (barely differences of $0.0000000001$). Even  numbered grids have a similar DoS too but different from odd ones ($100$ vs. $101$ above). $72\times72\times72$ is the only odd (english) one that matches odd (math) grids.

Any reason for all of this? Which one should I use?

Find some data below (click to zoom in!):

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: That color scheme is brutal to look at, yellow on white is hard to read.  Might confuse people taking quick glances

Comment: @TristanMaxson, haha, that is true, but I always find green, blue, and red challenging to differentiate, whereas yellow somehow works for me. In final presentations, I go for the classic RGB.

Comment: Sadly, I know nothing of this problem though.  Maybe it is a similar issue to k-points, does a shifted grid make sense in this context?  That might be helpful to plot.

Comment: Hitanshu, have you thought about an answer to @TristanMaxson's question? We have to get the unanswered queue reduced in size!

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned. It can be reopened with clarification from the OP or if another user would like to provide an answer.

Comment: @Tyberius I don't think I can improve the question anymore except change the colouration in the graph. I think a question about any differences in odd and even meshes would be better. If it's alright, can I delete this question?

Comment: You don't necessarily need to delete this question, but I think a new question about odd/even meshes more generally would be interesting.